# Decrypt TLS in Wireshark with (pre-)master key

Tags: tls1.2, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have been following the documentation about decrypting TLS using (pre-master) key, stored in (the `RSA Session-ID:xxxx Master-Key:yyyy` format) but it still won't decrypt it properly. I am using TLSv1.2 with `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` but that shouldn't be the problem with master key (contrary to RSA private key). Here is the debug log:

https://gist.github.com/rvansa/a75479dabac23b4435eacef91c185fd4

Regrettably I am not sure which of the error-ey messages are red herrings and where the problem is. AFAIU the master key is loaded correctly...

Comment: Cross linking with Wireshark forums: https://ask.wireshark.org/question/29175/tls-decryption-does-not-work/

Comment: Also found a very similar (unanswered) question: https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/61107/problem-with-ssl-decryption/